# JAX-RS Form within a Widfly

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, wildfly

I need to do a REST call to an interface. For this, I use the following code:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
Response res = client.target(url).
    request().
    header("Authorization", "Basic " + basicAuthString).
    buildPost(Entity.form(new Form("grant_type", "client_credentials"))).
    invoke();
```

Within a standalone application with JAX-RS, this works as expected. When I use that code within a Wildfly application server, I get the following error:

```
20:16:15,186 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) Caused by:
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form
```

Wildfly does not know how to handle `javax.ws.rs.core.Form`, which creates the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Which dependency do I miss?

[**EDIT**:2016-07-07]

This error occurs for any data I want to send. This throws a similar error:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
Response res = client.target(url).
    request().
    post(Entity.entity("DATA", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

Comment: .
    Add this in your request or check what content type it is expecting and add that in header header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

Comment: Results in the same error.

Comment: Try adding @Consumes ( "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ) on the API to which it is calling

Comment: It's an API provided by another party. This error occurs _within_ the Wildfly, as soon I create the request. The request never leaves the server.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after one day of debugging: Removing the ClientConfig is the solution!

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response res = client.target(url).
    request().
    post(Entity.entity("DATA", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```